# Pycharm 2.0 - How to disconnect a Django project from SVN?

Tags: svn, pycharm

In Eclipse, I usually right click on my project and do Team -> Disconnect to disconnect my project from the repository.

How can I do the same in Pycharm? I looked around but could not find any option that will let you disconnect your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Version Control`, change the mapping from **Subversion** to **None**.

Comment: I tried this. It still does not clear out the .svn folder in the project directory. I had to go in and manually delete the .svn folders in all the project root directory and sub-directories.

Comment: You are right, PyCharm doesn't delete physical .svn files, if you want to delete them all, just run the following command in the project directory: `find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That would make a good feature addition to Pycharm. When a free IDE has it, a paid one should definitely have it!